# Fill pandas dataframe missing data based on correlation with other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a pandas DataFrame with many rows and a column of strings named `error_text` that contains several empty values. I wanted to fill these missing data based on the correlation of this column with another one.

```
mydf_example = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,3],'b':[10,20,30,40,50,60,30],'c':['a','b','c','d','e','f','c'], 'error_text':[np.nan,'some_text','other_text',np.nan,'more_text','another_text',np.nan]})
mydf_example

    a   b   c   error_text
0   1   10  a   NaN
1   2   20  b   some_text
2   3   30  c   other_text
3   4   40  d   Nan
4   5   50  e   more_text
5   6   60  f   another_text
6   3   30  c   NaN
```

First I created a `sub_df` dropping the rows of missing data:

```
mydf_example = mydf_example.dropna()
mydf_example

    a   b   c   error_text
1   2   20  b   some_text
2   3   30  c   other_text
4   5   50  e   more_text
5   6   60  f   another_text
```

Then I converted the `error_text` column to category and calculated the correlation:

```
mydf_example['error_text'] = mydf_example['error_text'].astype('category').cat.codes
mydf_example.corr()['error_text']

a            -0.989949
b            -0.989949
error_text    1.000000
```

I was thinking if there is a way to fill the missing data in the `error_text` column based on the data of the other columns, for example, the last row would be filled with 'other_text', as the other values are equal to row 2. Of course, in my original dataset the correlation (or descorrelation) is not high as in the example, but I didn't find a way to set a value based on this info.

Comment: The logic is unclear, you want to correlate the arbitrary codes with the actual numerical values of the other columns? It doesn't really make sense. What would be the expected output?

Comment: The number of different strings present in 'error_text' are limited, so I can treat them as categories. What I wanted was to replace the NaN values with one of these strings based on the correlation with other columns. For example the row number 6 (the last one), I would replace NaN for "other_text", as the other values of it matches perfectly with row number 2.

Comment: OK, but the code of the category is arbitrary and depends on the initial order, this doesn't really make sense to correlate them, why should code 3 be closer to 1 than code 4? This doesn't make sense from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. I didn't explain it well, actually each column is category, not values, so there would not be any distance between the numbers, as they are simply different categories and identified by numbers.

Comment: Yes it would, `corr` would use the numbers, how else would it compute a distance for the correlation? :)

Comment: I was thinking to do something like this, that I just found: [How to measure the correlation between two categorical variables in python](https://thinkingneuron.com/how-to-measure-the-correlation-between-two-categorical-variables-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be treated as a machine learning problem, more specifically supervised classification.

You have a training dataset (`sub_df`) with known labels (`error_text`). The task is to derive a rule for inferring the label (a.k.a. target) from the other columns (`a`, `b`, `c`), known in this context as features. You would have to assume that this rule is independent of the reasons for missing label data.

The target is categorical, so this is a classification problem.
All the features are categorical, so you need to think about their encoding. If the categories have meaningful order and distances from each other, it may make sense to encode them as numbers and treat them as such. Also consider appropriate scaling. Otherwise, one-hot encoding is a common choice if there are few categories.

Depending on these decisions, pick a suitable classification algorithm. For example, a random forest classifier may be a good choice, as implemented in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest). Look at the documentation and take it from there.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good approach that can work as well